# How to fetch only those fields (events) from database which have not occurred yet in an event management webapp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

My database contains an events table with startsat and endsat timestamps which stores the datatime of the event's starting and ending time.
I also have an index page to list all events but I want only those events to be displayed which are yet to occur, sorted in ascending order.

My specifications:

```
Rails: 5.2.0
Database: PostgreSQL (production) sqlite3 (dev)
```

Comment: Yeah I was using order to sort using created_at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the date fields are `startsat` and `endsat` and model name is `Event`, you can make use of below query:

```
Event.where('startsat > ?', Time.current).order(:created_at)
 => Records that start after current time
```

Find the documentation [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions) and [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering).

Comment: You might need to update the answer based on what field OP wants the records to be sorted. But so far so good.